# How to create a combo box button

Tags: java, swing

Does this component exist in Java? It is a a button with an attached combo box.
[image]

Comment: No, you would have to place a JButton to the right of a JComboBox.  You can, however, use an ActionListener to act on a combo box selection.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html

Answer (score 0):

I have similar component which I developed in one of my own projects.
Please replace all the custom components (Like - CToolBarButton to JButton, CPanel to JPanel, CButton to JButton) wherever required. You also can use custion UI classes to get the desired look and feel.

```
package com.custom.ui.base.control;

import com.custom.ui.base.border.ToolbarButtonOptionsBorder;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuListener;

/**
 * This is Options button in for ToolBar. This Toolbar button can contain other toolbar buttons those
 * would be displayed in the popup
 *
 * @version 1.0.0.1 (Jul 29, 2010)
 * @author Arindam Roy
 */
public class CToolbarButtonOptions extends CToolBarButton implements ActionListener, PopupMenuListener {

    /**
     * Holds number of buttons in the Popup
     */
    int count = 0;

    /**
     * Holds the Columns in the popup
     */
    private int maxColumnCount = 3;

    /**
     * Creates new form BeanForm
     */
    public CToolbarButtonOptions() {
        initComponents();
        init();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes additional components in this screen
     */
    private void init() {
        jPopupMenu.add(dmPanel);
        setListeners();
    }

    /**
     * Adds listeners to the components
     */
    private void setListeners() {
        this.addActionListener(this);
        this.jPopupMenu.addPopupMenuListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * Adds a Toolbar button in the popup
     *
     * @param toolBarButton <code>CToolBarButton</code> instance to add in the popup
     * @see CToolBarButton
     * @see #remove(com.dbm.base.control.DMToolBarButton)
     */
    public void add(CToolBarButton toolBarButton) {
        dmPanel.add(toolBarButton);
        toolBarButton.addActionListener(this);
        count++;
        updateLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Returns components of Option button popup menu
     *
     * @return <code>Component[]</code> that contains components of popup menu
     */
    public Component[] getPopupComponents() {
        return dmPanel.getComponents();
    }

    /**
     * Removes a Toolbar button from the popup
     *
     * @param toolBarButton <code>CToolBarButton</code> instance to remove from the popup
     * @see CToolBarButton
     * @see #add(com.dbm.base.control.DMToolBarButton)
     */
    public void remove(CToolBarButton toolBarButton) {
        toolBarButton.removeActionListener(this);
        count--;
        dmPanel.remove(toolBarButton);
    }

    /**
     * Recognize the columns and rows to place popup menu buttons in the Popup
     */
    private void updateLayout() {
        if (dmPanel.getLayout() instanceof GridLayout) {
            int row = (count / getMaxColumnCount());
            if (count % getMaxColumnCount() > 0) {
                row++;
            }
            int column = count >= maxColumnCount ? maxColumnCount : count;
            if (!(row == 0 && column == 0)) {
                ((GridLayout) dmPanel.getLayout()).setRows(row);
                ((GridLayout) dmPanel.getLayout()).setColumns(column);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        jPopupMenu = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu();
        dmPanel = new com.custom.ui.base.container.CPanel();

        jPopupMenu.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(38, 144, 72)), javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255))));

        dmPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1, 1, 0, 1));

        setBorder(new ToolbarButtonOptionsBorder());
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(25, 8));
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    /**
     * Action Handler for Action Events
     *
     * @param e <code>ActionEvent</code> instance that holds the event details
     */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == this) {
            jPopupMenu.show(this, 2, this.getBounds().y + this.getBounds().height + 1);
        } else {
            jPopupMenu.setVisible(false);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of columns, according to that the Popup menu buttons are placed
     *
     * @return <code>int</code> column count in the popup menu for button placement
     * @see #setMaxColumnCount(int)
     */
    public int getMaxColumnCount() {
        return maxColumnCount;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the number of columns, according to that the Popup menu buttons are placed
     *
     * @param maxColumnCount <code>int</code> column count in the popup menu for button
     * placement, to set
     * @see #getMaxColumnCount()
     */
    public void setMaxColumnCount(int maxColumnCount) {
        this.maxColumnCount = maxColumnCount;
        updateLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Action handler for Popup menu listener. This method handles the event of "popup menu visible"
     *
     * @param e <code>PopupMenuEvent</code> instance that holds the event details
     */
    public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
        this.getModel().setRollover(true);
    }

    /**
     * Action handler for Popup menu listener. This method handles the event of "popup menu visible"
     *
     * @param e <code>PopupMenuEvent</code> instance that holds the event details
     */
    public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
        this.getModel().setRollover(false);
    }

    /**
     * Action handler for Popup menu listener. This method handles the event of "popup menu visible"
     *
     * @param e <code>PopupMenuEvent</code> instance that holds the event details
     */
    public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {
        this.getModel().setRollover(false);
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private com.custom.ui.base.container.CPanel dmPanel;
    private javax.swing.JPopupMenu jPopupMenu;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

This will look like:
[image: this]

Custom Border class:

```
package com.custom.ui.base.border;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

/**
 * This border for toolbar button component holds group of buttons. Clicking on this, one popup comes that
 * contains all the options buttons available against this toolbar button.
 *
 * @version 1.0.0.1 (Sep 15, 2010)
 * @author Arindam Roy
 */
public class ToolbarButtonOptionsBorder extends EmptyBorder {

    /**
     * Indicates width of the Down arrow icon width
     */
    private int optionArrowWidth = 7;

    /**
     * Creates new instance of ToolbarButtonOptionsBorder
     */
    public ToolbarButtonOptionsBorder() {
        super(new Insets(4, 4, 4, 8));
    }

    /**
     * Paints the border for the specified component with the specified position and size.
     *
     * @param c the component for which this border is being painted
     * @param g the paint graphics
     * @param x the x position of the painted border
     * @param y the y position of the painted border
     * @param width the width of the painted border
     * @param height the height of the painted border
     */
    @Override
    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        super.paintBorder(c, g, x, y, width, height);
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        int xPoints[] = new int[]{x + width - optionArrowWidth - 1, x + width - 1, x + width - 2 - (optionArrowWidth / 2)};
        int yPoints[] = new int[]{y + (height / 2) - 1, y + (height / 2) - 1, y + (height / 2) + 3};
        g.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, xPoints.length);

        g.drawLine(x + width - optionArrowWidth - 2, y + 5, x + width - optionArrowWidth - 2, height - 3);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        xPoints = new int[]{x + width - optionArrowWidth, x + width - 2, x + width - 2 - (optionArrowWidth / 2)};
        yPoints = new int[]{y + (height / 2) - 1, y + (height / 2) - 1, y + (height / 2) + 2};
        g.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, xPoints.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is ToolbarButtonOptionsBorder class?

Comment: It's a custom border class. I have added it into my answer.